# Javascript Component not working of Materialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I want to use Materialize Framework but I am not able to use its JAVASCRIPT Component, the waves-button worked but the rest of all are not working, I searched on Net and found first call jquery before Materialize but that did not solve my problem ..

This is my index.html Page and my init.js is

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/materialize.min.css">
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/materialize.js"></script>
        <script src="js/init.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
                <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>


(function ($) {
    $(function () {

        // Initialize collapse button
        $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
        // Initialize collapsible (uncomment the line below if you use the dropdown variation)
        //$('.collapsible').collapsible();
        $('.button-collapse').sideNav('show');

    }); // end of document ready
})(jQuery);
// end of jQuery name space
```

I call  jquery.js first than materialize.js but it is not working.

Comment: Any console error ?

Comment: Can you add a fiddle? That helps figuring out the problem.

Comment: put your codes in jsfiddle please?

Comment: Use a recent version of jQuery. Preferably, load from a CDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you sent is working :

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    // Initialize collapse button
    $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
    // Initialize collapsible (uncomment the line below if you use the dropdown variation)
    //$('.collapsible').collapsible();
    $('.button-collapse').sideNav('show');
  }); // end of document ready
})(jQuery); // end of jQuery name space
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jzob32ed/

So which jquery version are you using ? materialize ? Any other framework that conflicts with jquery ? Can you dump in your question the console output.

Comment: Version of my jquery is 1.3.2

Comment: And version of materialize is v0.97.5

Comment: Ok I think its your jquery version, if I remember well materialize is compatible with jquery > 2

Comment: Yes you are right after using cdn linkk it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle which walks you through a basic structure of a navbar with a slide-out on the toggle of the hamburger icon. I have used jQuery 2.2.0 and Materialize 0.97.5.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/callmeaatrey/wo3fxL66/)

Javascript:

```
(function ($) {
  $(function () {
     $('.button-collapse').sideNav({
        menuWidth: 300, // Default is 240
        closeOnClick: true
      );
      $('.collapsible').collapsible();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Markup(HTML):

```
<nav>
  <ul class="hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed">
      <li class="bold"><a href="#!" class="">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
      <li class="bold"><a href="#!" class="">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
</nav>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Problem was with version if jquery now I used CDN link it is working. thanks